# How to access a library of methods?

Tags: python, django

I need consume some methods defined in a library.
In my module, I have

`/mymodule/lib/mod.py`

And my `views.py` in `/mymodule/views.py`

In my `mod.py` I have declared:

```
class ModClient(object):
    """REST client for Mod API"""

    def __init__(self, client_id, secret, environment):
        self.client_id = client_id
        self.secret = secret
        self.environment = environment

    def _base_url(self):
        base_url = ''
        if self.environment == 'sandbox':
            base_url = 'https://sandbox.mod.com'
        elif self.environment == 'development':
            base_url = 'https://development.mod.com'
        elif self.environment == 'production':
            base_url = 'https://production.mod.com'
        return base_url


    def _base_params(self):
        params = {
            'client_id': self.client_id,
            'secret': self.secret
        }
        return params

    def _parse_response(self, response):
        result = response.json()
        if response.status_code != 200:
            raise ModClientException(message='HTTP status {}: {}'.format(response.status_code, result),
                                       http_status=response.status_code,
                                       error_type=result.get('error_type', None),
                                       error_code=result.get('error_code', None))
        return result

    def get_accounts(self, access_token):
        url = '{}/accounts/get'.format(self._base_url())
        params = self._base_params()
        params['access_token'] = access_token
        response = requests.post(url, json=params)
        return self._parse_response(response)
```

How I can access to my method `get_accounts` from my `view.py` assuming that both are in the same module?

Comment: Can you instantiate `ModClient` in view.py and then call that `instance.get_accounts(<some access_token>)` ?

Comment: `mod.py`, `view.py` sound very much like two different modules to me! You mean they are in the same package (`mymodule.lib possibly`)?

Comment: yes, sorry, differente packages, `views.py` is in `/mymodule/views.py`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `mymodule` is a package itself and its containing folder is in your environment's `PYTHONPATH`, import the class via:

```
from lib.mod import ModClient
```

Then you should be able to instantiate the class in the view and call methods on the instance:

```
mc = ModClient()
accounts = mc.get_accounts(token)
```

A proper IDE (PyCharm, Eclipse, etc.) will do auto-imports for you.